# How to debug incompatible shapes in gradient calculation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape, tensorflow-xla

I am sorry to post this without a toy reproducible example. I am slowly adding @tf.function decorators to my code and I came across a new error that I don't even know how to begin attacking.

Does this smell like anything you have seen before. Any pointers in the right direction would be very useful.

#### Error message

This popped up when calling tape.gradient. 16 is the expected size of the input to softmax (it is the value for n_to_keep if you are following the code below)

```
ERROR Incompatible shapes: [16] vs. [2087866608]
     [[{{node gradients/Softmax_grad/mul}}]]
    tf2xla conversion failed while converting __inference___backward_get_broadcast_inputs_146142_146192[_XlaMustCompile=true,config_proto=3175580994766145631,executor_type=11160318154034397263]. Run with TF_DUMP_GRAPH_PREFIX=/path/to/dump/dir and --vmodule=xla_compiler=2 to obtain a dump of the compiled functions. [Op:__inference___backward_get_broadcast_inputs_146142_146192]
```

#### Problem code (I think)

I unfortunately can't share my entire script but this is the only function that is using softmax. Please pardon the code quality.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def extract( foo, sorted_I, n_to_keep, num_partitions ):
    # split by segment into a list called bar
    bar = tf.dynamic_partition(
        foo,
        sorted_I,
        num_partitions
    )
    # unsplit after extracting the best few elements
    best = tf.concat(
        [A[:n_to_keep] for A in bar],
        axis=-1
    )
    return best, bar

@tf.function(jit_compile=True)
def get_broadcast_inputs( ci_edge_heats, ci_edges_I, n_to_keep, num_partitions ):

    ci_edge_heats = tf.reshape(ci_edge_heats, [-1])
    sorted_indices = tf.argsort(ci_edge_heats, axis=0, direction="DESCENDING")

    sorted_I = tf.gather( ci_edges_I, sorted_indices )

    node_ids = tf.range(tf.shape(ci_edge_heats)[0])
    sorted_node_ids = tf.gather( node_ids, sorted_indices )

    best_indices, _ = extract(
        sorted_node_ids,
        sorted_I,
        n_to_keep,
        num_partitions
    )

    best_I, _ = extract(
        sorted_I,
        sorted_I,
        n_to_keep,
        num_partitions
    )

    sorted_heats = tf.gather( ci_edge_heats, sorted_indices )
    partitioned_heats = tf.dynamic_partition(
        sorted_heats,
        sorted_I,
        num_partitions
    )

    weights = tf.concat(
        [ tf.nn.softmax(A[:n_to_keep]) for A in partitioned_heats],
        axis=-1
    )

    return best_indices, weights, best_I
```

###### What did you try and what were you expecting?

I am not fluent enough to try dumping the compiled functions, like the error message suggests. I'd love advice on how to sift through the dumps to find clues to this bug.